# Boto3 S3: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto, boto3

Trying to upload file to S3 with:

```
    # boto3 s3 client
    s3.put_object(Bucket=self.bucket,
                  Body=open(upload_file, 'rb'),
                  Key=k.key,
                  SSECustomerAlgorithm='AES256',
                  SSECustomerKey=base64.b64encode(data_key),
                  SSECustomerKeyMD5=base64.b64encode(data_key_md5)
                  )
```

and got error on this line:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

my `upload_file` variable is `<type 'file'>` with `dir`:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'close', 'closed', 'encoding', 'errors', 'fileno', 'flush', 'isatty', 'mode', 'name', 'newlines', 'next', 'read', 'readinto', 'readline', 'readlines', 'seek', 'softspace', 'tell', 'truncate', 'write', 'writelines', 'xreadlines']
```

Switching to `open(upload_file, 'rb').read()` won't help. Also my files could be large (1gb pr so), it is not reasonable keep them as string.

I know it would work if I set `upload_file` to filepath, but I don't have this file on a disk, it is submitted through a form.

## UPDATE

Its weird, but when I use test file or string (for test sake) got similar problem:

`TypeError: expected string or buffer`

This is response for:

```
# boto3 s3 client
s3.put_object(Bucket=self.bucket,
    # put existing filr
    Body=open('/tml/existing-file', 'rb'), # adding read() wont help
    # ...
)
```

same for strings:

```
# boto3 s3 client
s3.put_object(Bucket=self.bucket,
    # put existing filr
    Body='some random string',
    # ...
)
```

Comment: What error do you get when you set `Body=open(upload_file, 'rb').read()`?

Comment: @wilbur 
`*** TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found` this file is from form, `<open file '<fdopen>', mode 'w+b' at  ***>`

Comment: And what if you just pass `upload_file` to `Body` instead of trying to open it?

Comment: @wilbur if i pass `upload_file` i got error `TypeError: expected string or buffer` same for `upload_file.read()`

Comment: Could you provide a full traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why I cant make it work with boto3, but here working code with previous, boto2 version. The only difference is: you need to add put parameters in header, according to official docs:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html 
In my code case sample, it wood look like:

```
    headers.update({
        'x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm': 'AES256',
        'x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key': base64.b64encode(data_key),
        'x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key-MD5': base64.b64encode(data_key_md5)
    })

    k.set_contents_from_file(upload_file, headers=headers)
```

As you see `upload_file` work fine, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you write your input stream into a temporary file and use `Bucket.upload_file` to transfer the file. It's not good to keep large files in memory in a web-service application. Consider you have multiple concurrent upload requests, this would consume a lot of memory in total.

```
import tempfile
import shutil
file_ = file_like_object_from_form_submit
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmpfile:
    shutil.copyfileobj(file_, tmpfile)
    tmpfile.flush()
    self.bucket.upload_file(tmpfile.name, path)
```

Comment: was trying to avoid this.. But will try and give you feedback

Comment: Only half true. A file-like object is a valid Body for `put_object`, but not for `upload_file`

Comment: @jordon-phillips do you have better idea?

Comment: Modified the answer according to Jordon's comment.